# i got 404 using Spring MVC, Tomcat 9.0.11, Maven, Intellij idea ultimate

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I need some help...

When i run my web-app, i get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. I already created the new project, reinstalled Tomcat.......but i always get 404.

You can see the project structure below:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZRyv.png)

Tomcat settings: [tomcat settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpzI0.png)

Web-app code:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>EmployeeFrom.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```